# Accepted conventions when using 'this' with function.apply

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a primitive type of Polish Notation Calculator and I'm using an object to define each operation.

Such that calling

```
new RPNCalculator().calculate([4, 5, '+']);
```

will produce an answer of 9 or

```
new RPNCalculator().calculate([4, 5, '+', 3, 5, '+', '*']);
```

will produce an answer of 72.

The code is here:

```
function RPNCalculator(arr) {

    this.calculate = function(arr) {
        var resultArr =[];
        for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(typeof(arr[i]) == 'number') {
                resultArr.push(arr[i]);
            }
            else {
                var a = resultArr.pop();
                var b = resultArr.pop();
                var c = opers[arr[i]].apply(this, [a, b]);
                resultArr.push(c);
            }
        }
        return resultArr.pop();
    }

    var opers = {
        "+": function(a, b) { return a + b; },
        "-": function(a, b) { return a - b; },
        "*": function(a, b) { return a * b; },
        "/": function(a, b) { return a / b; }
    }
}
```

The calculations work correctly, but what I would like to know is whether the following line

```
var c = opers[arr[i]].apply(this, [a, b]);
```

is the best way to invoke the required function contained inside the `opers` object based on the symbol at the current index in the array, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a reference to `this` in your code, because the functions aren't working on any class members.

In this case, you can simply do:

```
var c = opers[arr[i]](a, b);
```

Which is a little cleaner.  To be the most readable, however, I recommend this:

```
var operator = opers[arr[i]];
var c = operator(a, b);
```

Comment: ...and to be more robust, I would use `var c = operator ? operator(a, b) : parseInt("");`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when you say the functions aren't working on class members, how do you mean? do you mean that a and b should be members of RPNCalculator?

Comment: It's hard to explain in a little space, but you are doing it correctly (having a and b be local variables).  When you use `Function.apply` or `Function.call`, you are effectively assigning and object to represent `this`.  If you just call the method directly (as in my example), you are leaving the default value for `this`, which varies highly upon how the method was created and where it was found.  You would need `apply` if the long-term state on `this` mattered, but it doesn't in your case.